# Ruby way to loop and check subsequent values against each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array that contains dates and values. An example of how it might look:

```
[
  {'1/1/2010' => 'aa'}, 
  {'1/1/2010' => 'bb'}, 
  {'1/2/2010' => 'cc'}, 
  {'1/2/2010' => 'dd'}, 
  {'1/3/2010' => 'ee'}
]
```

Notice that some of the dates repeat. I'm trying to output this in a table format and I only want to show unique dates. So I loop through it with the following code to get my desired output.

```
prev_date = nil
@reading_schedule.reading_plans.each do |plan|
  use_date = nil
  if plan.assigned_date != prev_date
    use_date = plan.assigned_date
  end
  prev_date = plan.assigned_date
  plan.assigned_date = use_date
end
```

The resulting table will then look something like this

```
1/1/2010 aa
         bb
1/2/2010 cc
         dd
1/3/2010 ee
```

This work fine but I am new to ruby and was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: I'd like to see the code used to generate the sample data. That code could probably be changed to make it a lot easier to get your desired format. The array of hashes with single key/value pairs is not too common.

Comment: The data is in this format because it matches my model. My model instance has a date and string field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enumerable.group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Enumerable.html#M002717) is a good starting point:

```
require 'pp'

asdf = [
  {'1/1/2010' => 'aa'}, 
  {'1/1/2010' => 'bb'}, 
  {'1/2/2010' => 'cc'}, 
  {'1/2/2010' => 'dd'}, 
  {'1/3/2010' => 'ee'}
]

pp asdf.group_by { |n| n.keys.first }.map{ |a,b| { a => b.map { |c| c.to_a.last.last } } }
# >> [{"1/1/2010"=>["aa", "bb"]}, {"1/2/2010"=>["cc", "dd"]}, {"1/3/2010"=>["ee"]}]
```

Which should be a data structure you can bend to your will.

Comment: A lot of people don't. There are some really cool methods hidden away in the Core libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know as though it's better, but you could group the values by date using (e.g.) `Enumerable#reduce` (requires Ruby >= 1.8.7; before that, you have [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003129)).

```
arr.reduce({}) { |memo, obj|
  obj.each_pair { |key, value|
    memo[key] = [] if ! memo.has_key?(key);
    memo[key] << value
  }
  memo
}.sort

=> [["1/1/2010", ["aa", "bb"]], ["1/2/2010", ["cc", "dd"]], ["1/3/2010", ["ee"]]]
```

You could also use [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002173) to similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally a job for a hash.

Create a hash and use the date as the hashkey and an empty array as the hashvalue.

Then accumulate the values from the original array in the hashvalue array

Comment: A hash is very efficient... you might also look into Enumerable#group_by -- check it out in irb to see if you are getting the results you want.